# Ik rig severely deforms, target pole rotates torso?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

[image: nodesc] For some reason my rig's targer pole isn't working properly. I was trying to practice rigging poses by using an image as reference, but I didn't know why my pose was limited and it wasn't deforming cleanly or realistically. I tried to clear the pose using alt s and alt r and alt g but for some reason it isn't working.

[image: nodesc]

I tried using forward kinematics but my rig seemed to deform like paper, but I'm not sure what to do to make it move realistically

Comment: Perhaps uploading the blend file would be helpful in this case as it appears to need some work. I believe it may need some manual weight painting. I assume you've tried painting the weights? Also perhaps you've set the new pose as the default rest pose accidently?

Comment: Oh, right! I'm sorry about that, it would've made things a bit easier to diagnose http://www.filedropper.com/posedgirl_1

Comment: Wow, First couple of glances at the file. I can see why this is extremely complicated for you. There are a lot of bones that lack names so knowing/remembering which bone does what and where is very difficult without names. Another thing is that the bones are not symmetrical and probably have parenting issues. My advice is, start over with this and keep your workflow organised and logical. Name your bones and do one side first and any bones you want mirrored to the other side you can do if you add .L after the bone name. (eg. "forearm.L").

Answer (score 0):

I think what had happened was that there were as I suspected, weighting issues, hierarchial problems and bones had been edited in the wrong mode which can cause problems with the set rotation, scale and location in pose mode.

Here I've given you an example of a rigify rig which comes with names and and logical hierarchy. It will need weight painting to fix deformations of limbs but it'll give you a head start.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xhietllb671q0k/posed%20girl_edit.blend?dl=0

Good luck with it